# StreamBuilder error Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

In my application I am using appsflyer for deep linking.

https://pub.dev/packages/appsflyer_sdk

The application works as expected. But if I reload the application via code. It gives me this error.

```
The following StateError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#39b5e):
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

The code that is causing this error is;

```
  _loadLandingView(Stream<Map> onData, Stream<Map> onAttribution,
      Future<bool> Function(String, Map) trackEvent) {
    return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: onAttribution?.asBroadcastStream(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return _detectOperation(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            return LandingView();
          }
        });
  }
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

I have seen controllers can be used with streams. Can it be used here?

Comment: you can unsubscribe that stream or dispose the widget screen

Comment: The widget does not get disposed. It is the View I am reloading. But how do I dispose the stream? I don't have a reference. Or reset or restart.

Comment: Can anyone provide help on this?